# "Object doesn't support this property or method" javascript error

Tags: javascript

Getting this error in IE8 and IE7.  Only have a bit of experience with javascript but trying to debug someone else's code at work.  Googled up some causes and using the same variable name as some classes can cause the error but doesnt seem to be the case here.

http://pastebin.com/WBXYh9Wu

```
<tbody id="urlLinkTableBody">
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${!empty urlLinkUrls}">
        <c:forEach var="urlLinkUrl" items="${urlLinkUrls}" varStatus="status">
            <tr id="urlLinkRow${status.index}">
                <td align="left">
                    <c:if test="${!vo.injectViewMode}">
                        <span id="editUrl${status.index}">
                            ${urlLinkUrl}
                        </span>
                        <input id="editUrlHidden${status.index}" type="hidden" name="urlLinkUrls" value="${urlLinkUrl}"/>
                    </c:if>
                    <c:if test="${vo.injectViewMode}">
                        <a href="javascript:windowPop('${urlLinkUrl}')">${urlLinkUrl}</a>
                    </c:if>
                </td>
                <c:if test="${!vo.injectViewMode}">
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        jQuery('#editUrl${status.index}').editInPlace({
                            callback: function(original_element, newvalue, original){
                                if (isUrl(newvalue)) {
                                    document.getElementById('editUrlHidden${status.index}').value = newvalue;
                                    return newvalue;
                                }
                                alert("Invalid URL");
                                return original;
                            },
                            show_buttons: true
                        });
                    </script>
                </c:if>
```

Comment: Have you included the relevant jQuery plugin for `editInPlace`?

Comment: But on which line do you get the error ?

Comment: Can you provide more info about the error? Is there any object or line of code referenced in the original error reported by IE?

Comment: yes I checked that the editInPlace plugin is included, it doesn't really show what line has the error in my code, it shows this

`User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; MS-RTC LM 8)
Timestamp: Tue, 7 Feb 2012 17:42:13 UTC

Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 19
Char: 15990
Code: 0
URI: https://xxxxxxx.com/javascript/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js`

Comment: added a pastebin of the code http://pastebin.com/WBXYh9Wu

Answer (score 0):

First off, check you have included the script for the `editInPlace` plugin.

Secondly, depending on how the plugin works, you may need to add your code within a document ready handler,like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery('#editUrl${status.index}').editInPlace({
            callback: function(original_element, newvalue, original){
                if (isUrl(newvalue)) {
                    document.getElementById('editUrlHidden${status.index}').value = newvalue;
                    return newvalue;
                }
                alert("Invalid URL");
                return original;
            },
            show_buttons: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Tried it, and it made the editing stop working.  I've added a pastebin link to the whole code http://pastebin.com/WBXYh9Wu